# How to save data from URL to asset folder?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite

In my app I use a database that is saved in asset folder. That works fine.

Now I'm getting some new data from a URL. How do I store that new sat in my assets folder?

Comment: You can not write into the file of assets folder. Because resource folder of an android application is readonly. You have to copy your database from assets to sdcard and in sdcard you can update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my app I use a database that is saved in asset folder. That works fine.

If by "database" you mean SQLite, it "works fine" because you copied the data out of assets and into internal or external storage.

> Now I'm getting some new data from a URL. How do I store that new sat in my assets folder?

You don't. As GrisHu indicates, assets are read-only at runtime. Your choices are:

1. Ship a new version of your APK that contains the new database in assets, or
2. When your app downloads the new database, it stores that on internal or external storage.